# Toast in webview not disappear onProgresseChanged

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, android-toast

in my webview i want create a toast when the page is loading and when the progress is 100% i want that the toast disappear.. Actually doesn't work. This is the code

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                    activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    if(progress == 100)
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                    activity.setTitle("My WebView");
                    toast.cancel();
                }
            });
```

In this way the toast doesn't appear web i load a page... If i remove `toast.cancel();` the toast appears but never disappears.. How can i solve?

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this

```
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                        activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                        activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                        if(progress == 100)
                           {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finish...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                           }
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                        activity.setTitle("My WebView");
                    }
                });
```

Or else Try like this,

```
this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
            setContentView(R.layout.info);

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.show();

            WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, final int progress)
                {
                    activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                    activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress );




                    if(progress == 100)
                    {
                        activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finish...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.show();
                    }

                }
            });

            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Comment: well the idea is different.. You write the toast when is finished the loading.. Ok it's another way and for me it's ok.. But now the progress bar not appears (i mean using the first code you posted). How can i show that always when i load a page?

Comment: i solved putting `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);` inside the if condition like the toast.. Ok it's good now :) but i don't know why i can see the progress bar only for the first loading page.. If i click in some link doesn't appear